# Code works in Editor but not with a Button

Tags: vba, excel, button, paste

So I have a small bit of VBA code that I used to carryover rows of data in Excel based on some specific criteria. If column S contains "1" it copies the row to the next sheet. There are usually around 40 to 50 rows to copy of around 80 to 100 and the rows that get copied are not always contiguous, but when it pastes them in they are. The code works dynamically by using `ActiveSheet.Next`.

```
Sub FwdCases()
Dim strsearch As String, lastline As Integer, tocopy As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("S:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

strsearch = "1"
lastline = Range("A200").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2

For i = 2 To lastline
    For Each c In Range("S" & i & ":S" & i)
        If InStr(c.Text, strsearch) Then
            tocopy = 1
        End If
    Next c
    If tocopy = 1 Then
        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Next.Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
tocopy = 0
Next i

ActiveSheet.Range("S:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ActiveSheet.Next.Select

End Sub
```

This code works absolutely fine. Both in the editor and when called from a button. However I recently discovered that it was also copying & pasting a TON of extra conditional formatting (hundreds of redundancies), so I went to change the copy paste method to `PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas` but apparently I've implemented it wrong, because now the code only works properly when called from the editor. When I run it using the button it only copies over 2 rows then jumps 2 sheets ahead (**not 1**) and stops.

I changed:

```
Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Next.Rows(j)
```

to:

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Rows(j).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Why is this simple change wreaking so much havoc?

**EDIT:** Expanded first paragraph.

Comment: Your question doesn't include the error message/description. "doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description.

Comment: There is no error message. If you read my last paragraph I state "When I run it using the button it only copies over 2 rows then jumps 2 sheets ahead and stops." That is the only error present to describe.

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly referring to your sheet i.e.

```
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(j).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

Agreeing with the comments below, I've removed the `.Next` from the syntax

Comment: do not use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Next` either. ... use `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`

Comment: ...also use `ThisWorkbook` or `Workbooks("Book1")`, for example. Rather than `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: The only downside with explicitly referring to sheets is that there are 12 sheets, one for each month, and I use the `ActiveSheet.Next` to get around having to declare each sheet. Right now it works totally dynamically. But if that's what's causing it I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just needed to break up the code with `Select` and use `Selection.PasteSpecial` instead of `ActiveSheet.Next.Rows(j).PasteSpecial`. It now works properly even when called via a button.

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Rows(j).EntireRow.Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
ActiveSheet.Previous.Select
```